# Default navigation link in Swiftui

Tags: swiftui, sidebar, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm working on an app the uses traditional sidebar navigation with a detail view. I've synthesized the app to illustrate two issues.

1. when the app starts, the detail view is empty. How can I programmatically select an entry in the sidebar to show in the detail view?
2. The sidebar allows swipe to delete. If the selected row (the one showing in the detail view) is deleted, it still shows in the detail view. How can update the detail view with, for example, an empty view?

Here's the source code for the app illustrating the issues:

```
import SwiftUI

class Model: ObservableObject {
  var items = [Item("")]
  
  static var loadData: Model {
    let model = Model()
    model.items = [Item("Books"), Item("Videos"), Item("Pics"), Item("Cars")]
    
    return model
  }
}

class Item: Identifiable, Hashable {
  static func == (lhs: Item, rhs: Item) -> Bool {
    lhs.name == rhs.name
  }
  
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
  }

  let id = UUID()
  
  @Published var name: String
  
  init(_ name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}


@main
struct IBTSimulatorApp: App {
  @StateObject var model = Model.loadData
    
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
        .environmentObject(model)
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach($model.items, id: \.self) { $item in
          NavigationLink(item.name, destination: Text(item.name))
        }
        .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
      }
      .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing)  {
          Button(action: addItem) {
            Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func addItem() {
    withAnimation {
      model.items.append(Item("New item (\(model.items.count))"))
      model.objectWillChange.send()
    }
  }

  private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
    withAnimation {
      model.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
      model.objectWillChange.send()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. you can use the `NavigationLink` version with tag and selection, and save the active selection in a persisted `AppStorage`var.

For 2. I expected you can set the selection to nil, but that does not work for some reason. But you can set it to the first item in the sidebar list.

As a general note you should make `Item` a struct instead of a class. Only the published Model should be a class.

```
class Model: ObservableObject {
    var items: [Item] = []
    
    static var loadData: Model {
        let model = Model()
        model.items = [Item("Books"), Item("Videos"), Item("Pics"), Item("Cars")]
        
        return model
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable { // Change from class to struct!
    
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var model = Model.loadData
    
    @AppStorage("selectemItem") var selected: String? // bind to persisted var here
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(model.items) { item in //no .id needed as Item is identifiable
                    NavigationLink(tag: item.id.uuidString, selection: $selected) { // use link with selection here
                        Text(item.name)
                    } label: {
                        Text(item.name)
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing)  {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Text("Nothing selected")
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            model.objectWillChange.send()
            model.items.append(Item("New item (\(model.items.count))"))
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
//            model.objectWillChange.send() // not necessary if Item is struct
            self.selected = nil // for some reaseon this does not work
            self.selected = model.items.first?.id.uuidString // selects first item
            model.items.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the design suggestions. They make sense. #2 appears to be solved with your changes. But #1 still isn't working. The app still shows "Nothing selected" upon a re-start. Something appears to be missing with the use of AppStorage.

Comment: #1 won't work in the dummy project as you don't save any items and the UUID is created new each time. Once items and UUIDs are saved it should work.

Comment: if you change UUID to Int and init with a fixed id it also works in the dummy. I just checked.